# delphi xe6 No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: android, ios, delphi, unicode, indy

The following code works on Win32, anyway it is trowing exception if run on Android or iOS. The exception is : "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page"

```
function GetURLAsString(aURL: string): string;
    var
      lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
      lStream: TStringstream;

    begin
      lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      lStream := TStringstream.Create(result);//create('',EEncoding.utf8),not work
      try

        lHTTP.Get(aURL, lStream);
        lStream.Position := 0;
        result := lStream.readstring(lStream.Size);//error here
      finally
        FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
        FreeAndNil(lStream);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: There is no question here, please clarify. Mobile platforms only handles UTF-16 unicode strings.

Comment: @LURD Indy is able to translate from and to UTF-16 on mobile platforms (supported by OS specific conversion APIs)

Comment: note: TIdHTTP.Create(nil) can be shortened to TIdHTTP.Create

Comment: @mjn, as Remy says, TStringStream is not up to do the job here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TStringStream` is not a suitable class for this situation.  It requires you to specify an encoding in its constructor.  If you do not, it uses the OS default encoding instead.  On Windows, that default is locale-specific to the user account that is running your app.  On mobile, that default is UTF-8 instead.

HTTP can transmit text using any number of charsets.  If the data does not match the encoding used by the `TStringStream`, you are going to run into decoding problems.

`TIdHTTP` knows the charset of the received data and can decode it into a Delphi `string` for you, eg:

```
function GetURLAsString(aURL: string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := lHTTP.Get(aURL);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I use this ,it isn't  trowing exception ,but some character cannot be displayed,use stringstream can display on win32,

Comment: You are using a Unicode version of Delphi. It does not matter what OS you are running on, a Delphi `string` always uses UTF-16 on all platforms, and `TIdHTTP` knows how to decode data to UTF-16 on all platforms based on the reported charset of the source data. If you are having trouble displaying characters, then either the source data is encoded with a different charset than it reported, is encoded using a charset that Indy or the OS does not support, or you are simply not displaying the string correctly.

Comment: If the data displays OK on Windows when using a `TStringStream` with a default encoding, but does not display OK on Android, the most likely reason is the transmitted data is encoded using Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) or similar charset, but the HTTP reply is not reporting that. `TIdHTTP` would save the raw bytes as-is directly into the `TStringStream`, which then decodes the bytes using its own default encoding, which is 8bit Ansi on Windows but is UTF-8 on mobile. Using the code I gave you above, the HTTP reply's charset is important so it must be accurate or else the data will not decode properly.

Comment: So that puts the burden on the HTTP server to report the correct charset to begin with.  If you provide the actual URL you are downloading, I can tell you if it is reporting the charset correctly or not. If it is, then I can look for a bug in Indy's decode logic (assuming you are using the latest Indy release).  If it is not, that needs to be addressed on the server side instead.

Comment: server is PHP script,use 'json_encode' and 'urldecode',**urldecode** error is here?,The question should be here，I will try.thank you very much.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: PHP script use "*urldecode*" ,so It's not UTF-8,I find it ,thank you