# "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page" error

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe7

I have a bug report showing an `EEncodingError`. The log points to `TFile.AppendAllText`. I call `TFile.AppendAllText` is this procedure of mine:

```
procedure WriteToFile(CONST FileName: string; CONST uString: string; CONST WriteOp: WriteOpperation; ForceFolder: Boolean= FALSE);     // Works with UNC paths
begin
 if NOT ForceFolder
 OR (ForceFolder AND ForceDirectoriesMsg(ExtractFilePath(FileName))) then
   if WriteOp= (woOverwrite)
   then IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText (FileName, uString)
   else IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText(FileName, uString);
end;
```

This is the information from EurekaLog.

[image]

[image]

What can cause this to happen?

Comment: similar issue with Delphi 10.2

Comment: Yeah... & years later and the bug is still here!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060832/delphi-xe6-no-mapping-for-the-unicode-character-exists-in-the-target-multi-byte

Comment: bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41439

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This program reproduces the error that you report:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils;

var
  FileName: string;

begin
  try
    FileName := TPath.GetTempFileName;
    TFile.WriteAllText(FileName, 'é', TEncoding.ANSI);
    TFile.AppendAllText(FileName, 'é');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Here I have written the original file as ANSI. And then called `AppendAllText` which will try to write as UTF-8. What happens is that we end up in this function:

```
class procedure TFile.AppendAllText(const Path, Contents: string);
var
  LFileStream: TFileStream;
  LFileEncoding: TEncoding; // encoding of the file
  Buff: TBytes;
  Preamble: TBytes;
  UTFStr: TBytes;
  UTF8Str: TBytes;
begin
  CheckAppendAllTextParameters(Path, nil, False);

  LFileStream := nil;
  try
    try
      LFileStream := DoCreateOpenFile(Path);
      // detect the file encoding
      LFileEncoding := GetEncoding(LFileStream);

      // file is written is ASCII (default ANSI code page)
      if LFileEncoding = TEncoding.ANSI then
      begin
        // Contents can be represented as ASCII;
        // append the contents in ASCII

        UTFStr := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Contents);
        UTF8Str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Contents);

        if TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(UTFStr) = TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8Str) then
        begin
          LFileStream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soEnd);
          Buff := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Contents);
        end
        // Contents can be represented only in UTF-8;
        // convert file and Contents encodings to UTF-8
        else
        begin
          // convert file contents to UTF-8
          LFileStream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
          SetLength(Buff, LFileStream.Size);
          LFileStream.ReadBuffer(Buff, Length(Buff));
          Buff := TEncoding.Convert(LFileEncoding, TEncoding.UTF8, Buff);

          // prepare the stream to rewrite the converted file contents
          LFileStream.Size := Length(Buff);
          LFileStream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
          Preamble := TEncoding.UTF8.GetPreamble;
          LFileStream.WriteBuffer(Preamble, Length(Preamble));
          LFileStream.WriteBuffer(Buff, Length(Buff));

          // convert Contents in UTF-8
          Buff := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Contents);
        end;
      end
      // file is written either in UTF-8 or Unicode (BE or LE);
      // append Contents encoded in UTF-8 to the file
      else
      begin
        LFileStream.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soEnd);
        Buff := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Contents);
      end;

      // write Contents to the stream
      LFileStream.WriteBuffer(Buff, Length(Buff));
    except
      on E: EFileStreamError do
        raise EInOutError.Create(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    LFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The error stems from this line:

```
if TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(UTFStr) = TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(UTF8Str) then
```

The problem is that `UTFStr` is not in fact valid `UTF-8`. And hence `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(UTFStr)` throws an exception.

This is a defect in `TFile.AppendAllBytes`. Given that it knows perfectly well that `UTFStr` is `ANSI` encoded, it makes no sense at all for it to call `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString`.

You should submit a bug report to Embarcadero for this defect which still exists in Delphi 10 Seattle. In the meantime you should not use `TFile.AppendAllBytes`.

Comment: What about TStreamReader? Seems a decent alternative and it is not based on IOUtils.

Comment: Perf is a bit dodgy. I don't want to advise without knowledge of the file's lifetime and who else modifies it.

Comment: This defect still exists in Delphi 10.4 too and it affect other functions such as DecodeStream for decoding Base64.

Comment: A somehow similar bug report was closed as "not a bug": https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41439

Comment: Trying one more time: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41533

Comment: Why did you take my complete program, a console app, and turn it into a part program that cannot be run directly. Do you know about [mcve]? I was about to submit that program as a report anyway ......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Hi David. I already changed it to minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

In this way it will work:

```
TFile.WriteAllText(FileName, 'é', TEncoding.UTF8);
```